# Oracle migrate from WE8ISO8859P1 to UTF-8 character encoding for schema table objects only

Tags: oracle, utf-8, character-encoding

The current encoding of oracle instance is WE8ISO8859P1 and needs to be moved to UTF-8. I have found some challenges in my database instance due to its current setup and requirements of my business.

This instance in question has 100+ schema users with number of tables created under each schema. We can say logically each schema exists for application or specific system within the enterprise. The requirement is to move only certain schema and their table objects to new character set of UTF-8.

Also, remember the reason for this migration right now is compliance with Restful POST calls that will perform CRUD operations in UTF format.

NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET- AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET- WE8ISO8859P1

I did do some research earlier and here are my findings.

• Oracle doesn’t support character encoding at the tablespace , table or column level. Therefore options start reducing for any charset migration strategy at schema level only.

• We have CRUD calls by other enterprise legacy systems to this schema. Therefore should not have a any wider impact. Off course, other schema's in this instance doesn't have any requirements of UTF-8.

The only way I see a solution is

**OPTION 1** - Move the target schema and thier objects into new database instance with NLS_LANGUAGE to be UTF-8.

**OPTION 2** - Converting all the relevant columns to NCHAR and NVARCHAR but with loss of length and truncation.

Both the approaches lead to big impact and not able to conclude what is best. Any suggestions are welcome that solves my charset migration without impact and changes to other schema in the instance.

Comment: Did you follow this document: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011 ? Why do you like to migrate only single schema? Usually the client should not notice any difference if you migrate the character set. The database character set is just the definition how Oracle database stores the data **internally**.

Comment: Converting columns to NCHAR and NVARCHAR seems to be a poor solution. Nowadays with UTF-8 (i.e. AL32UTF8) there is actually no reason to use such data types anymore. The support for NCHAR and NVARCHAR is decreasing, many new native Oracle functions (esp. related to XML) do not support these data types.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit, Thanks for your comment. You are right on moving the whole instance. But then there is definite regression due to the character size change. We are a German entity and it might not be simple 1 to 1 byte mapping between WE8ISO8859P1 and UTF-8. Therefore sizing of same CHAR or VARCHAR will change. I will try to get into the doc you have shared. But idea is to minimize regression on enterprise instance changes.

Comment: If the columns are defined as `VARCHAR2(xx CHAR)` rather than `VARCHAR2(xx BYTE)` then you don't need to change any sizes.

Comment: You suggestion is valid. I think it will apply when we migrate the instance to new character set apply global semantics at NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=CHAR level. Do you see any impact if I have existing client machines that send data still in WE8ISO8859P1 encoding. The OS is set at that level but database at UTF-8. If so then I can suggest migrating to new instance with CHAR semantics.

Comment: No, if a client character set is WE8ISO8859P1 or anything else nothing will change. The client will make proper conversion is needed. See https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html